Identifying a derivative in $\mathfrak{su}(2)\times \mathfrak{su}(2)$ in $\mathfrak{so}(4)$
I identified the Lie algebra $\frak{so}(4)$ with the skewsymmetric matrices with basis $\{C_{i,j}\}_{1\leq i < j\leq 4}$ wich has only a $1$ on the $i,j$-th entry and a $-1$ on the $j,i$-th entry. Now I fix a lift of $SO(4)$ to $Spin(4)$. Given a path $\gamma(t):\mathbb R\rightarrow SU(2)\times SU(2):(\pmatrix{e^{it} & 0\\ 0 & e^{-it}},\pmatrix{e^{it} & 0\\ 0 & e^{-it}})$.
The paper I am reading claims that $\frac{d\gamma}{d t}|_{t=0}=-2\ C_{3,4}$. I would appreciate some hints how to get there.
I see that $\frac{d\gamma}{d t}|_{t=0}=(\pmatrix{i & 0\\ 0 & -i},\pmatrix{i & 0\\ 0 & -i})$, but how can I identify that with $C_{3,4}\in\frak{so}(4)$? I know that $\frak{so}(4)\cong \frak{spin(4)}$. I sadly dont know how $Spin$ covers $SO$ or how the identification of $Spin(4)\cong SU(2)\times SU(2)$ looks like. Do I need to find the explicit identification and lift or are there other methods to see the claim.
